# Modify woocommerce orders.php columns but leave quotes.php as it is

Tags: php, woocommerce

I am trying to change the columns in the orders overview (orders.php) in the Woocommerce My Account page. I got this working now but now it is changed in the quotes overview (quotes.php) as well.

Any ideas how to change the columns **only** in the orders overview?

This is what I did so far and what works well for the orders overview.

In the functions.php

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_account_orders_columns', 'new_orders_columns' );
function new_orders_columns( $columns = array() ) {

        // Unsets the columns which you want to hide
        unset( $columns['order-total'] );
                unset( $columns['order-number'] );
                unset( $columns['order-date'] );
                unset( $columns['order-status'] );
                unset( $columns['order-total'] );
                unset( $columns['order-actions'] );


    // Add new columns
        $columns['rechnungsnummer'] = __( 'Rechnung', 'woocommerce' );
        $columns['order-date'] = __( 'Rechnungsdatum', 'woocommerce' );
        $columns['order-status'] = __( 'Status', 'woocommerce' );
        $columns['lieferdatum'] = __( 'Voraussichtliches Lieferdatum', 'woocommerce' );
    $columns['tracking'] = __( 'Tracking', 'woocommerce' );

    return $columns;

}
```

In the orders.php

```
<?php elseif ( 'tracking' === $column_id ) : ?>
            <?php
            $sendungsverfolgung_custom_field = get_post_meta($order->get_id(), 'rechnung_link', true);
            if ($sendungsverfolgung_custom_field == true) {
                echo '<a href="' . esc_html( get_post_meta($order->get_id(), 'rechnung_link', true)) . '" class="woocommerce-button button" target="_blank">Sendung verfolgen</a>';
                    } else {
                      echo "Folgt in Kürze";
                            }
                        ?>

<?php elseif ( 'rechnungsnummer' === $column_id ) : ?>
            <?php
            echo esc_html( get_post_meta($order->get_id(), 'rechnungsnummer', true));
            ?>

<?php elseif ( 'lieferdatum' === $column_id ) : ?>
            <?php
            echo esc_html( get_post_meta($order->get_id(), 'lieferdatum', true));
            ?>
```

Comment: Not sure in what context the `quotes.php` gets shown/used, but perhaps you can use one of the conditional tags to differentiate between the two places/situations ...? https://woocommerce.com/document/conditional-tags/

Comment: Thanks. I tried to use conditional tags in the functions code. But I always get an error, no matter what condition I choose: `Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'unset' (T_UNSET) in`-- PS: The quotes.php shows also a list of orders but with the status of a request that has not been purchased.

Comment: Then you should go check [PHP parse/syntax errors; and how to solve them](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18050071/1427878).

Comment: OK got it now. the error was in the conditions. I used `is_wc_endpoint_url( 'orders' )`